# ListView in LinearLayout not visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I am experiencing layout issues in my `NavigationView`. The goal is to provide a header and a list view with an adapter. First, I had this code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.plaxxt.plaxxt1"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
(...)
           </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start">

                <include layout="@layout/drawer_header" />

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/lst_menu_items" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this results like the following (header is there, no list)

[image]

If I replace the header with a dummy image, both appear though:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/lst_menu_items" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

The result is:

[image]

So we see that the list is correctly generated with my adapter.

If I remove the image and leave the `ListView` as the only child of the `LinearLayout`, the drawer remains empty.

Where is the mistake? Please help me out...

Comment: Make `NestedScrollView` height `match_parent`, LinearLayout `wrap_content` and ListView `wrap_content`

Comment: @Piyush sorry, no effect...

Comment: I also suggest to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.

Comment: provide orientation to the linear layout.

Comment: why can't you use default android NavigationDrawer with prebuild menu?

Comment: @HonorLT because it was always empty. Including the header layout was the first thing which made *anything* appear in the drawer.

Comment: @seon It was the solution, thanks!

Comment: Happy coding mate

Comment: @seon of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try adding Orientation to the LinearLayout**

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"  
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/lst_menu_items" />

            </LinearLayout>
```